# Can't select Spinner item when receive server data

Tags: android

i can't select spinner item that i received from server.
i have some `Person` Class objects come from server in a list of array. then i collect the names of objects from `PersonList` to `PersonNames`

```
personList = response.body();
  for(Person p : personList){
  personNames.add(p.getPersonFullName());
}
```

im using retrofit 2 to receive data from server.
Fortunately spinner show names (in a first look in spinner no item selected but when i press the dropdown menu the names shown all!).
But i can't select.But when i add some item manualy like `PersonNames.add("Hi");` Spinner works fine and select item in offline work. But in getting data from server and turn them to another list , i can't use spinner and select item. what's going wrong?

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, personNames);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerPersons.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinnerPersons.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ePersonUserName.setText(personNames.get(i));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: give the code that you populate the spinner

Comment: @DimDim Spinner code Added!